# How to find files in a Debian system not installed or created by dpkg?

Tags: debian, apt, find, uninstall, dpkg

I've installed some things manually in the past and would like to weed out all related files. So, I need a way to automatically find all the files (in /usr, for example) that are not included in any of the packages currently installed on the Debian system. However, I would also need to filter out the files that are created during package installation (by dpkg post-install scripts and similar things).

Comment: See also this question:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18038/how-to-list-files-and-folders-that-are-not-maintained-by-any-deb-package

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the [`cruft-ng`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/cruft-ng) package:

> cruft-ng is a program to look over the system for anything that shouldn't
> be there, but is; or for anything that should be there, but isn't.

Comment: Note that as of 2022-10-07, cruft was removed from testing and may disappear from Debian.

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like this:

```
dpkg -L --list-all-package-files | grep "^/usr" > dpkg-files.dat   **(don't know the dpkg option "--list-all-package-files", read mand dpkg)**
find /usr -type f -o -type l > all-usr-files.dat
sort dpkg-files.dat all-usr-files.dat | uniq -c | grep " 1 "
```

This way you will get all files that are in /usr but not any package file.
As a first shot this could help you.

Comment: I can't find any way to get -L to list more than one package at a time, but you can get the same effect from `grep -h "^/usr" /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list > dpkg-files.dat`

Comment: There is no `--list-all-package-files` option.

Comment: @DerfK: You can get -l to list more than one package, for example like this: `dpkg -L \`aptitude search ~i -F "%p"\``

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there are more files or links in /usr than actually listed by dpkg. For example, /usr/bin/aptitude exists, probably created by some post-installation script, but it's not listed by dpkg. So, I guess what I want here is a list of files installed **or** created by installing any package (will change question).

Comment: @Karol: Other sources of files could be diversions and alternatives.  The output is in sentence form but you can see diversions with `dpkg-divert --list` as root (These are usually given a suffix).  Alternatives are a bit harder, the file format in /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/ is awkward and `update-alternatives` tells me just about everything BUT the name of the link. `find /usr -lname '/etc/alternatives/*'` is probably the easiest way to get these.